# How to set up email notifications for certain strings in Nginx access.log?

Tags: linux, grep, nginx

I would like to be notified every time a line with a certain string appears in my Nginx's access.log.

I imagine a certain combination of a continuously running tail + `grep -w 'foobar' /var/log/nginx/access.log` + a send email command (I have an SMTP on a remote server) can give me the results I'm looking for, but I'm not sure at all about the specifics.

Any kind souls can advise here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this does the job:

```
    #! /bin/sh
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log |
grep --line-buffered 'foobar' |
while read line
do
    echo "$line" | mail -s "Subject" -aFrom:username\<useremail@domain.com\> recipient@domain.com
done
```